# ERROR:tensorflow: Image directory '' not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying out Tensorflow for Poets from [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#0) with Windows 10. And I'm having troubles when I ran this code:

```
python retrain.py 
\--bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks 
\--how_many_training_steps=500 
\--model_dir=tf_files/models/ 
\--summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/%ARCHITECTURE% 
\--output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb 
\--output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt 
\--architecture=%ARCHITECTURE% 
\--image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

This is the error that I got

```
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
ERROR:tensorflow:Image directory '' not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "retrain.py", line 1326, in <module>
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
 File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
   _sys.exit(main(argv))
 File "retrain.py", line 989, in main
    class_count = len(image_lists.keys())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

How can I solved it? I have already tried upgrading and downgrading Anaconda, Tensorflow and Python.

Comment: The error clearly says that your image directory is not correctly set-up Also the code was compiled in Linux Environment so you need to change the slashes(back and front accordingly)